# Grab and Store Data from XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get data from a API that output data in XML structure.

It has a lot branches, looks complicated. Here is the structure,

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<item>
<title>Test Video</title>
<media:content url="http://localhost/video/test.mp4" type="video/x-flv" duration="6474"/>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I would also like to know what if it got more branches such as video description, type.. how can I grab them? and inside media tag it has multiple values, how can I get them separately? example: how to get the **content url** inside **media tag**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize there's a namespace in your XML (line 1), this will do the trick:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming your XML in $x
$contents = $xml->xpath("//media:content");

foreach ($contents as $content) echo $content['url'],"<br />";
```

See live demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7bJf9Q

Alternatives: look for `namespace` and `simplexml`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use SimpleXMl. `<media:content>` refers to a namespace (http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/). So you can use:

```
$string = <<<XML
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<item>
<title>Test Video</title>
<media:content url="http://localhost/video/test.mp4" type="video/x-flv" duration="6474"/>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

//var_dump($xml);
echo $xml->channel->item->title;
$contentAttr = $xml->channel->item->children('media', true)->content->attributes();
echo $contentAttr['url'];

exit;
```

Take also a look at [Using SimpleXML to read RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887300/using-simple-xml-to-read-rss-feed)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `simplexml`or `DOMDocument` at php.net.
These provide functions to parse XML-data.
The url inside the `<media:content>` is called an attribute, the above functions provide ways to pull the attributes, as well.

I suggest you try something with the info I've given, and return to SO in case you need help, ok?

Have fun trying!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know the names for those things to search on google, but after I posted this question I kept searching and I found some stuff on stackoverflow, ok @michi , I'll comment if I need help. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Hi, Now I know how to grab data but still can't do anything with that multi valued attribute, echo $xml->channel->item->title; - this works fine but echo $xml->channel->item->media:content; this doesnt..

Comment: @naveencgr8 see my new answer!