# Accessing Json value of variable with a colon (:) in between using Php

Tags: php, json, variables

I need to access the value of a variable element in Json, the problem however the variable has a colon (:) and i keep getting undefined variable every time.

```
{#370 ▼
  +"im:name": {#371 ▶}
  +"im:image": array:3 [▶]
  +"im:itemCount": {#380 ▶}
  +"im:price": {#381 ▶}
  +"im:contentType": {#385 ▶}
  +"rights": {#387 ▶}
  +"title": {#388 ▶}
  +"link": {#390 ▶}
  +"id": {#391 ▶}
  +"im:artist": {#393 ▶}
  +"category": {#396 ▶}
  +"im:releaseDate": {#397 ▶}
}
```

for example `$feed->category` is okay , 
but anything with : in between like `$feed->im:category` throws an error.

Comment: What is the source of this data?

Comment: @NigelRen rss json from iTunes, why?

Comment: Could be worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887300/using-simplexml-to-read-rss-feed,although https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250679/best-way-to-parse-rss-atom-feeds-with-php and a few others may also help.

Comment: simplexml_load_string in some cases does not capture all the details neede

Comment: I would be surrised that it misses anything and converting it to JSON can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: I didn't convert it to json, it was optional to use either xml or json, it is simpler for me to work with json than xml except for the case with colon.

Answer (score 6):

Use curly brace syntax

```
$feed->{'im:category'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `json_decode` it and force the use of associative arrays with `JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY`.